# Netbeans jPanel changes to another jPanel after specific time

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer, jpanel

i am working on jumbled quiz game in netbeans..i need some help..i want to jump from one jPanel to another and show that new jPanel for specific time period and then automatically show any other jPanel...the jPanel which i am trying to show for specific time period contains jumbled questions and their answers so that a person can see that panel for specific time...so how to set show time for a jPanel??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Timer and TimerTask classes to perform specific tasks at certain fixed time intervals. They are types of Thread. Look at the api for more information about them.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

For a rough idea on how to use them in your case,

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //Hide the JPanel
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
```

The above code creates a new object of the timer class. The scheduleAtFixedRate() method takes three method parameters.

1. A TimerTask Object
2. An initial delay, i.e. after how many milliseconds the TimerTask should start.
3. Repeat Time Interval, i.e. after how many milliseconds the TimerTask should repeat its execution.

To enable a timer to perform more than one task, simply create a new TimerTask object, and call the scheduleAtFixedRate() method on the Timer, specifying the new TimerTask, and the time after which it should repeat itself.

Any number of tasks can be scheduled to run by using a single Timer. For any more information about Timers and TimerTask, refer javadoc API for these classes.

Comment: ya sure..sir i wan to ask one more thing can we use more than one timer in a single button to show different jpanels?? and how different timers can be used??and what is 0,5000 in above example..pls do reply..thnk u

Comment: and sir also tell me how to stop this timer??